# bad argument #3 to 'Text' (string expected, got nil)

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a place in roblox. And i wrote script, Look at it, and please, say what wrong with it???
In another scripts all works perfectly!, you can help me with it?

```
    local players = game.Players:GetChildren()
    local pupil = players[math.random(0,#players)]
    local James = game.Workspace.James
    local Texte = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Maintexzt
    local nameq = game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.Maintexzt.Nameq
    function ontouch(hit)
    if hit.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid") then
    print("Trigget working!")
    James.Humanoid.Torso.CFrame = game.Workspace.OutOfhere.CFrame
    script.Parent.CFrame = game.Workspace.SpawnLocation.CFrame
end
end
    script.Parent.Touched:Connect(ontouch)
    function ontouchexit()
Texte.Text = "Uh... We did it??"
wait(2)
nameq.Text = players.Name
Texte.Text = "Oh how we make it?"
wait(2)
nameq.Text = James.Name
Texte.Text = "Better, go home!"
wait(3)
nameq.Text = players.Name
Texte.Text = "Go!"
nameq.Text = James.Name
Texte.Text = "But go to my home!"
nameq.Text = players.Name
Texte.Text = "Nope"
nameq.Text = James.Name
Texte.Text = "Your choice, Your die, You can follow me, or not"
end
script.Parent.TouchEnded:Connect(ontouchexit)
```

and please, say what wrong with it, I want to finish a develop the place.

Comment: Which line the error is generated at?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take your time and read [Help Center - Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Most of the problems like yours can be easily avoided by reading the error you have got and giving it some thought. This means that if you want our help - send us the full error message including line number and related code.

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
local Workspace     =   game.Workspace or workspace;
local StarterGui    =   game.StarterGui;
local players       =   game:GetService("Players");
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
local Pupil     =   Players[math.random(0,#Players)];
local James     =   Workspace:FindFirstChild("James");
local Texte     =   StarterGui.ScreenGui:FindFirstChild("Maintexzt");
local nameq     =   StarterGui.ScreenGui.Maintexzt:FindFirstChild("Nameq");
local Target    =   ""; --Stores any string value of players that touched the TouchPart
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ontouch(hit)
    if (hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")) then
        print("Trigger working!");
        Target                      =   hit.Parent.Name;    --Saves value of a player's name
        James.Humanoid.Torso.CFrame =   Workspace.OutOfhere.CFrame;
        script.Parent.CFrame        =   Workspace.SpawnLocation.CFrame;
    end
end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
function ontouchexit()
    --Replaced 'players.Name' into 'Target', which contains string
    Texte.Text = "Uh... We did it??"
    wait(2)
    nameq.Text = Target
    Texte.Text = "Oh how we make it?"
    wait(2)
    nameq.Text = James.Name
    Texte.Text = "Better, go home!"
    wait(3)
    nameq.Text = Target
    Texte.Text = "Go!"
    nameq.Text = James.Name
    Texte.Text = "But go to my home!"
    nameq.Text = Target
    Texte.Text = "Nope"
    nameq.Text = James.Name
    Texte.Text = "Your choice, Your die, You can follow me, or not"
    Target = ""; --Resets the value of who previously touched the TouchPart
end
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(ontouch)
script.Parent.TouchEnded:Connect(ontouchexit)
```

Edit: If it doesn't work, try replacing

```
function ontouch(hit)
    if (hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")) then
```

with this

```
function ontouch(hit)
    if (hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and hit.Parent.Name == players.Name) then
```

That checks whenever the person who touched it is an actual player, not from someone (NPC) who also have a humanoid as well

Answer (score 0):

```
local players = game.Players:GetChildren()
```

https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/GetChildren

> Returns an array (a numerically indexed table) containing all of the
>   Instance's direct children

```
nameq.Text = players.Name
```

Not being a Robolox expert I find it very unlikely that `players.Name` is anything but `nil`

Your code further suggests that assigning vlaues to those Text properties will call some function. That would explain the error message to me.

I don't think an array of players would say `"Uh... We did it??"` So I guess the solution to your problem is to find out who you actually want to talk and use that name.

Print `players.Name` and see for yourself.